# Will using Fortune allow me to collect more food?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I collect food from my farms, but I would like to collect as much as possible from them.  I have automatic farms on servers that you can sell your items.  I was wondering if by adding fortune to a tool would allow me to collect more food.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you will only get more:

- Carrots
- Potatoes
- Wheat seeds (*only* the seeds, not the main crop)
- Melon slices

So, yes, you **will get more food from collecting your crops with Fortune.**

Comment: With any fortune tool?

Comment: Yes, with any. @Jason_

Comment: I was collecting, for example, my crops with a Fortune Pickaxe and they yielded more food. @Jason_

Comment: Remember — the seeds aren't worthless; even if you don't farm chickens, you can still drop some stacks into a composting hopper to get more bone meal, which is quite generally useful

Answer (score 0):

For food from mobs (animals or monsters) you need looting, for food from crops (wheat, carrots, etc) it *will* in fact work.